# rsync to filter out certain directories

Tags: linux, bash, filter, rsync

I have a directory structure like this:

```
f001 pics 2015/...
f002 pics 2016/...
f003 pics 2017/...
f004 pics 2018/...
f005 pics 2019/...
f006 pics 2020/...
f007 pics 2021/...
f008 pics 2022/...
j001 pics 2020/...
j002 pics 2021/...
j003 pics 2022/...
r001 pics 2020/...
r002 pics 2021/...
r003 pics 2022/...
t001 pics 2020/...
t002 pics 2021/...
t003 pics 2022/...
```

Each folder contains plenty of pictures. Quite frequently, more folders are added. In reality there's several hundred already.

I want to copy all folders including its pictures starting with f only, excluding f001, f00, f00, f00, f00, f00,. Here my rsync command, executed in bash:

```
rsync -avtP --filter="+ /f*/" --filter="- /f001*/" --filter='- /f002*/' --filter='- /f003*/' --filter='- /f006*/' --filter='- /f007*/' --filter='- /f011*/' --filter='- *' "/data/source/" /data/destination/
```

What am I doing wrong? All folders starting with something else than f are filtered out, but eventhough I filter e.g. f001, it gets copied never the less. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this order:

```
--filter="- /f001*/" --filter='- /f002*/' --filter='- /f003*/' --filter='- /f006*/' --filter='- /f007*/' --filter='- /f011*/'
--filter="+ /f*/" 
--filter='- /*'
```

You may want to `--debug=FILTER`.

Each dir is checked against list of rules until match is found. When `+ /f*/` is first, any `f*` dir is matched against it and is `+` added. It has to be after excludes,so that one of `- /f001*/` matches it first.

Comment: Works with this filter order and after adding a slash to the last of the three to --filter='- /*'